# Compiling Haskell-mpi

Tags: haskell, mpi, cabal

After finally figuring out how to install all the required packages for haskell-mpi, I run:

```
sudo cabal install --global haskell-mpi
```

and, it gives a header error:

```
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring haskell-mpi-1.2.1...
Preprocessing library haskell-mpi-1.2.1...
dist/build/Control/Parallel/MPI/Internal.chs.h:1:17: error: mpi.h: No such file or directory
c2hs: Error during preprocessing custom header file
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
haskell-mpi-1.2.1 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

How do I link the header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked!

```
sudo cabal install --global --extra-include-dirs=/usr/lib/openmpi/include/ haskell-mpi
```

This is mentioned in the [readme](https://github.com/bjpop/haskell-mpi), but not in the [package page](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskell-mpi-1.2.0).

Answer (score 1):

You likely need to install your distribution's development package for MPI through your package manager. Look for one with `-dev` in the name; that seems to be a common convention.

Comment: I have already installed libopenmpi-dev, and I also tried setting the include path as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5759838/cannot-get-cabal-to-find-the-mpi-library-for-haskell-mpi-on-windows