# Why do I have to remove `ekg` from build-deps for haskell stack/cabal to find my dll on Windows?

Tags: haskell, dll, haskell-stack, ekg

I'm building a Haskell 7.10 project that depends on tdsodbc.dll, using stack v1.7.1 on Windows, everything 64-bit. I have tdsodbc.dll in the `lib` folder of the project, and `extra-lib-dirs: lib` and `extra-libraries: tdsodbc` in the .cabal.

But when I compile, I get `Missing C library: tdsodbc` when stack runs `cabal configure`. I've tried putting `extra-lib-dirs: [lib]` in `stack.yaml`, and I can see from that configure command that it has put `--extra-lib-dirs=C:\Users\Kevin\src\theproject\lib` on the cabal configure command line, but still complains about it missing.

Now the weird part: If I remove `ekg` from the `build-deps` of the project (and remove the relevant imports etc.), the project builds just fine! I still have to copy the dll into `.stack-work/dist/…` to make it *run*, but why would `ekg` in build-deps stop cabal from being able to configure it?

I've tried the trick from [Cannot get cabal to find the mpi library for haskell-mpi on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5759838/cannot-get-cabal-to-find-the-mpi-library-for-haskell-mpi-on-windows) with putting `c/Users/Kevin/src/theproject/lib` in `LIBRARY_PATH` (there's no `.a` file to mv in my case, and no .h's), but that didn't help me. Only removing `ekg` has helped me so far. What could be causing this? The "solution" seems completely irrelevant to the problem :(

---

EDIT: I tried using plain Haskell Platform 7.10.3 (from https://www.haskell.org/platform/prior.html ), and that configured and built just fine. So the problem is just when cabal configure is called from stack.